# Whole web page is being destroyed by a horizontal scroll bar.... can't do anything except to wait

Tags: html, css

I am developing a webpage but a horizontal scroll bar is present in the page. I want to remove it but can not. I have been into web development recently and most of web pages I made for practice faced the same problem.

I expect the following part of code to be faulty

---

> `.heading::before{border: 2px solid chocolate;`
>
> `content: "";`
>
> `height: 100vh;`
>
> `background: url(....) no-repeat center ;`
>
> `width: 100vw;`
>
> `position: absolute;`
>
> `top: 0px;`
>
> `left: 0px;`
>
> `z-index: -1; }`

---

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
nav{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    background-color: #15191f;
}
.heading{
    height: 90vh;
    
}
.heading::before{
    border: 2px solid chocolate;
    content: "";
    height: 100vh;
    background: url() no-repeat center ;
    width: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}
.flex{
    display: flex;
}
.flex-row{
    flex-direction: row;
}
.flex-column{
    flex-direction: column;
}
.wrap{
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.al-cen{
    align-items: center;
}
.ju-cen{
    justify-content: center;
}
nav a{

    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #15191f;
    color: #e3ecf3;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    border: 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
   
    
}
nav a:hover{
    color: #15191f;
    background-color: #e3ecf3;
}

#li1{
    margin-left: 50px;
}
#a1{
    margin: 0px 4px;
}
#a2{
    margin: 0px 4px;
}
#a3{
    margin: 0px 4px;
}
#a4{
    margin: 0px 4px;
}
nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
}
#logo{
    width: 5vw;
    border: 2px ;
    border-radius:100mm;

}
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
div ul{
    margin: 0px 40px;
}
body{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    background-color: #e3ecf3;
}
div{
    margin: 20px 15px;
}
ol li{
    margin: 0px 40px;
}

.block{
    display:block;
}
.inline-block{
    display: inline-block;
}
.border-red{
    border: 3.5px solid red;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
.border-green{
    border: 3.5px solid green;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.border-blue{
    border: 3.5px solid blue;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.line-height{
    line-height: 8vh;
    
}

ol{
    border: 2px solid blue;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    margin: 4px 0px;
    width:300px
}
.text-cen{
    text-align: center;
}
ol li{
    margin-left: 40px;
}
input{
    display: block;
}
option{
    background-color:#15191f;
    color:#e3ecf3;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
select{
    width: 85px;
    background-color:#15191f;
    color:#e3ecf3;
    height:30px;
    border: 2px solid #15191f;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.button{
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    /* border: 2px solid #15191f; */
    border-radius: 100px;
    /* background-color: #15191f; */
}
/* .button: */
.checkbox{
    /* background-color: #15191f; */
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>All in One</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/home.css">
    <script src="../JS/home.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="">
    <nav class="flex row al-cen">
        <img id="logo" src="../random_source" alt="Error loading image">
        <ul class="flex row">
            <li id="li1"><a id="a1" href="../HTML/home.html" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
            <li id="li2"><a id="a2" href="../HTML/about.html" target="_blank">About Us</a></li>
            <li id="li3"><a id="a3" href="../HTML/services.html" target="_blank">Our Services</a></li>
            <li id="li4"><a id="a4" href="../HTML/contact.html" target="_blank">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="heading flex flex-column al-cen ju-cen">
        <h1 class="line-height">All in ONE Website</h1>
        <p>This <strong>Website</strong> aims to <i>include</i> all that has been <em>learnt</em> and keep a record of
            it for future usage.</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="border-red firstpara">
        <p><b>
                <\b>This Bold<\b>
            </b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. <br><strong>
                <\br> Has been used here and here<\br><br>
            </strong> modi molestias omnis voluptate alias unde voluptates provident hic voluptatibus ipsum deleniti
            itaque
            delectus et expedita quisquam, non soluta, harum consequuntur sapiente rem quaerat. Repellendus, impedit.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="border-green lists">
        <div class="orderdlist block border flex-row ">

            <ol id="ol1" class="inline-block" type="1">
                <h6>OL type 1</h6>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            </ol>
            <ol id="olA" class="inline-block" type="A">
                <h6>OL type A</h6>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            </ol>
            <ol id="ola" class="inline-block" type="a">
                <h6>OL type a</h6>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            </ol>
            <ol id="olI" class="inline-block" type="I">
                <h6>OL type I</h6>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            </ol>
            <ol id="oli" class="inline-block" type="i">
                <h6>OL type i</h6>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="unorderedlist">
            <ul type="square">
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            </ul>
            <ul type="circle">
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            </ul>
            <ul type="disc">
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border-blue table text-cen flex flex-column wrap">
        <h3>This is a Table</h3>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Heading-1</th>
                    <th>Heading-2</th>
                    <th>Heading-3</th>
                    <th>Heading-4</th>
                    <th>Heading-5</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Row-1-Colum-1</td>
                    <td>Row-1-Colum-2</td>
                    <td>Row-1-Colum-3</td>
                    <td>Row-1-Colum-4</td>
                    <td>Row-1-Colum-5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Row-2-Column-1</td>
                    <td>Row-2-Column-2</td>
                    <td>Row-2-Column-3</td>
                    <td>Row-2-Column-4</td>
                    <td>Row-2-Column-5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Row-3-Column-1</td>
                    <td>Row-3-Column-2</td>
                    <td>Row-3-Column-3</td>
                    <td>Row-3-Column-4</td>
                    <td>Row-3-Column-5</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="border-red forms flex flex-column">
        <h1 class="text-cen">FORMS</h1>
        <h5>Below are some types of input we can ask on forms.Include a NAME in input tags
        </h5>
        <p>We will make input tag a block element to make go to next line and make the code look clean.
            Before it was inline so elements crammmed over each other.We can add value="" to show that thing.<br>
            The diff between value and placeholder is that the placeholder gets removed whan an item is entered, wheras
            when we enter an item at place of value, it concencates in the value. Placeholder is Background, value is
            not.
            @gmail.com is value below in email. Remaining are Placeholder
        </p>
        <form action="#">
            Button <input class="button" type="button" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Checkbox<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Color<input type="color" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Date<input type="date" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Datetime<input type="datetime" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Datetime-local<input type="datetime-local" placeholder="Placeholder"><p>Just Testing</p>
            Email<input type="email" value="@gmail.com" placeholder="Placeholder">
            File<input type="file" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Hidden<input type="hidden" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Image<input type="image" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Month<input type="month" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Number<input type="number" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Password<input type="password" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Radio<input type="radio" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Range<input type="range" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Reset<input type="reset" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Search<input type="search" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Submit<input type="submit" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Tel<input type="tel" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Text<input type="text" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Time<input type="time" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Url<input type="url" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Week<input type="week" placeholder="Placeholder">

            Select from a dropdown <select>
                <option value="Option-1-Val">Option-1</option>
                <option value="Option-2-Val">Option-2</option>
                <option value="Option-3-Val">Option-3</option>
                <option value="Option-4-Val">Option-4</option>
                <option value="Option-5-Val">Option-5</option>
            </select>

        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="entities border-green">
        <h4>We use entities for displaying some character</h4>
        &lt;
        <!-- Less Than -->
        &gt;
        <!-- Greater Than -->
        &pound;
        <!-- pound -->
        &copy;
        <!-- copy -->
        &rAarr;
        <!-- Arrow -->
        &frac12;
        <!-- In form of fraction -->
        
    </div>
    <div class="border-blue semanticelements">
        <p>A dropdown button which shows whatever is written in summary and when clicked reveals what is written in detail tag.</p>
        <details>
            
            <summary>I have keys but no doors. I have space but no room. You can enter but you can't leave. What am i?</summary>
            A Keyboard.

        </details>
        <p>Now i will use a time tag</p>
        <p>We will be celebrating new year on <time datetime="2022-12-12">December 12</time> in my house.</p>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

---

Specifically `width: 100vw` , if I remove this line the scrollbar disappears but so does the image.
`width:auto` also makes the picture disappears.

1. I want to display a background picture using this code (picture's address in url). If I remove this code the horizontal scroll bar disappears. Using a border shows that it is indeed the problem. **How can I hide scroll bar while displaying an image on whole screen, no matter the size**. (*I mean no part of screen should be left out*.)
   Most of the answers out there suggest to remove 100vw and 100% width but that removes the picture

---

If possible suggest other ways which will allow me to display image on full screen without causing any problems to the aesthetics. The picture should be in background and for a specific tag only, not whole webpage.

Comment: Make a runnable snippet with all of your code

Comment: The border adds extra width as you have noticed. Have you tried setting box-sizing: border-box?

Comment: @ZachJensz Done Snippet

Comment: @AHaworth As a quick check of what you mentioned, I wrote *{box-sizing:borderbox} in the css. It does not changes anything

Comment: What happened to the hyphen?

Comment: I removed the link of picture from the code but the problem still persists. Might be clear by the border shown.

Comment: @AHaworth Still nothing.
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the pseudo element I added `box-sizing: border-box` and changed the width to `100%` instead of `100vw`.

`box-sizing: border-box`

This changes which box is used when declaring absolute widths. When we set this to border-box, it means that the border is placed inside of the declared width, not adding to it.
i.e. I have a 100px wide box with 2px border, I want the border to be included in that 100px, not added to it.

`width: 100%`

Percent widths are relative to the width of the container, whereas viewport are relative to the viewport. 100% means take up all the width of the container I'm in, 100vw means take up all of the viewport width (including the scrollbar).

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  background-color: #15191f;
}

.heading {
  height: 90vh;
}

.heading::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid chocolate;
  content: "";
  height: 100vh;
  background: url() no-repeat center;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-row {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-column {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.al-cen {
  align-items: center;
}

.ju-cen {
  justify-content: center;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #15191f;
  color: #e3ecf3;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  border: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #15191f;
  background-color: #e3ecf3;
}

#li1 {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#a1 {
  margin: 0px 4px;
}

#a2 {
  margin: 0px 4px;
}

#a3 {
  margin: 0px 4px;
}

#a4 {
  margin: 0px 4px;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

#logo {
  width: 5vw;
  border: 2px;
  border-radius: 100mm;
}


/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */

div ul {
  margin: 0px 40px;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  background-color: #e3ecf3;
}

div {
  margin: 20px 15px;
}

ol li {
  margin: 0px 40px;
}

.block {
  display: block;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}

.border-red {
  border: 3.5px solid red;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.border-green {
  border: 3.5px solid green;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.border-blue {
  border: 3.5px solid blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.line-height {
  line-height: 8vh;
}

ol {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  /* display: inline-block; */
  margin: 4px 0px;
  width: 300px
}

.text-cen {
  text-align: center;
}

ol li {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

input {
  display: block;
}

option {
  background-color: #15191f;
  color: #e3ecf3;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

select {
  width: 85px;
  background-color: #15191f;
  color: #e3ecf3;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #15191f;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.button {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  /* border: 2px solid #15191f; */
  border-radius: 100px;
  /* background-color: #15191f; */
}


/* .button: */

.checkbox {
  /* background-color: #15191f; */
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>All in One</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/home.css">
  <script src="../JS/home.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="">
  <nav class="flex row al-cen">
    <img id="logo" src="../random_source" alt="Error loading image">
    <ul class="flex row">
      <li id="li1"><a id="a1" href="../HTML/home.html" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
      <li id="li2"><a id="a2" href="../HTML/about.html" target="_blank">About Us</a></li>
      <li id="li3"><a id="a3" href="../HTML/services.html" target="_blank">Our Services</a></li>
      <li id="li4"><a id="a4" href="../HTML/contact.html" target="_blank">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="heading flex flex-column al-cen ju-cen">
    <h1 class="line-height">All in ONE Website</h1>
    <p>This <strong>Website</strong> aims to <i>include</i> all that has been <em>learnt</em> and keep a record of it for future usage.</p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="border-red firstpara">
    <p><b>
                <\b>This Bold<\b>
            </b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. <br><strong>
                <\br> Has been used here and here<\br><br>
            </strong> modi molestias omnis voluptate alias unde voluptates provident hic voluptatibus ipsum deleniti itaque delectus et expedita quisquam, non soluta, harum consequuntur sapiente rem quaerat. Repellendus, impedit.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="border-green lists">
    <div class="orderdlist block border flex-row ">

      <ol id="ol1" class="inline-block" type="1">
        <h6>OL type 1</h6>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
      </ol>
      <ol id="olA" class="inline-block" type="A">
        <h6>OL type A</h6>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
      </ol>
      <ol id="ola" class="inline-block" type="a">
        <h6>OL type a</h6>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
      </ol>
      <ol id="olI" class="inline-block" type="I">
        <h6>OL type I</h6>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
      </ol>
      <ol id="oli" class="inline-block" type="i">
        <h6>OL type i</h6>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="unorderedlist">
      <ul type="square">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
      </ul>
      <ul type="circle">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
      </ul>
      <ul type="disc">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="border-blue table text-cen flex flex-column wrap">
    <h3>This is a Table</h3>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Heading-1</th>
          <th>Heading-2</th>
          <th>Heading-3</th>
          <th>Heading-4</th>
          <th>Heading-5</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Row-1-Colum-1</td>
          <td>Row-1-Colum-2</td>
          <td>Row-1-Colum-3</td>
          <td>Row-1-Colum-4</td>
          <td>Row-1-Colum-5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Row-2-Column-1</td>
          <td>Row-2-Column-2</td>
          <td>Row-2-Column-3</td>
          <td>Row-2-Column-4</td>
          <td>Row-2-Column-5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Row-3-Column-1</td>
          <td>Row-3-Column-2</td>
          <td>Row-3-Column-3</td>
          <td>Row-3-Column-4</td>
          <td>Row-3-Column-5</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="border-red forms flex flex-column">
    <h1 class="text-cen">FORMS</h1>
    <h5>Below are some types of input we can ask on forms.Include a NAME in input tags
    </h5>
    <p>We will make input tag a block element to make go to next line and make the code look clean. Before it was inline so elements crammmed over each other.We can add value="" to show that thing.<br> The diff between value and placeholder is that the placeholder
      gets removed whan an item is entered, wheras when we enter an item at place of value, it concencates in the value. Placeholder is Background, value is not. @gmail.com is value below in email. Remaining are Placeholder
    </p>
    <form action="#">
      Button <input class="button" type="button" placeholder="Placeholder"> Checkbox
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" placeholder="Placeholder"> Color
      <input type="color" placeholder="Placeholder"> Date
      <input type="date" placeholder="Placeholder"> Datetime
      <input type="datetime" placeholder="Placeholder"> Datetime-local
      <input type="datetime-local" placeholder="Placeholder">
      <p>Just Testing</p>
      Email<input type="email" value="@gmail.com" placeholder="Placeholder"> File
      <input type="file" placeholder="Placeholder"> Hidden
      <input type="hidden" placeholder="Placeholder"> Image
      <input type="image" placeholder="Placeholder"> Month
      <input type="month" placeholder="Placeholder"> Number
      <input type="number" placeholder="Placeholder"> Password
      <input type="password" placeholder="Placeholder"> Radio
      <input type="radio" placeholder="Placeholder"> Range
      <input type="range" placeholder="Placeholder"> Reset
      <input type="reset" placeholder="Placeholder"> Search
      <input type="search" placeholder="Placeholder"> Submit
      <input type="submit" placeholder="Placeholder"> Tel
      <input type="tel" placeholder="Placeholder"> Text
      <input type="text" placeholder="Placeholder"> Time
      <input type="time" placeholder="Placeholder"> Url
      <input type="url" placeholder="Placeholder"> Week
      <input type="week" placeholder="Placeholder"> Select from a dropdown
      <select>
        <option value="Option-1-Val">Option-1</option>
        <option value="Option-2-Val">Option-2</option>
        <option value="Option-3-Val">Option-3</option>
        <option value="Option-4-Val">Option-4</option>
        <option value="Option-5-Val">Option-5</option>
      </select>

    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="entities border-green">
    <h4>We use entities for displaying some character</h4>
    &lt;
    <!-- Less Than -->
    &gt;
    <!-- Greater Than -->
    &pound;
    <!-- pound -->
    &copy;
    <!-- copy -->
    &rAarr;
    <!-- Arrow -->
    &frac12;
    <!-- In form of fraction -->

  </div>
  <div class="border-blue semanticelements">
    <p>A dropdown button which shows whatever is written in summary and when clicked reveals what is written in detail tag.</p>
    <details>

      <summary>I have keys but no doors. I have space but no room. You can enter but you can't leave. What am i?</summary>
      A Keyboard.

    </details>
    <p>Now i will use a time tag</p>
    <p>We will be celebrating new year on <time datetime="2022-12-12">December 12</time> in my house.</p>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It WORKS, but before i mark this answer as correct, can you explain why this works and not the 100vw.

Comment: @BlaackWork It works because percent widths are relative to the width of the container, whereas viewport are relative to the viewport. 100% means take up all the width of the container I'm in, 100vw means take up all of the viewport width (including the scrollbar).

Comment: I've updated the question with more explanation

Comment: Any other way to do the same thing? Just asking. It's great to have a backup.

Comment: @BlaackWork haha thank you. You'll unlock the feature soon. Don't think there's another way to size the width relative to the parent, you should be fine with percentages for that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set box-sizing specifically for pseudo elements.

```css
*, *::before, *::after{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    background-color: #15191f;
}
.heading{
    height: 90vh;
    
}
.heading::before{
    border: 2px solid chocolate;
    content: "";
    height: 100vh;
    background: url() no-repeat center ;
    width: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}
.flex{
    display: flex;
}
.flex-row{
    flex-direction: row;
}
.flex-column{
    flex-direction: column;
}
.wrap{
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.al-cen{
    align-items: center;
}
.ju-cen{
    justify-content: center;
}
nav a{

    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #15191f;
    color: #e3ecf3;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    border: 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
   
    
}
nav a:hover{
    color: #15191f;
    background-color: #e3ecf3;
}

#li1{
    margin-left: 50px;
}
#a1{
    margin: 0px 4px;
}
#a2{
    margin: 0px 4px;
}
#a3{
    margin: 0px 4px;
}
#a4{
    margin: 0px 4px;
}
nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
}
#logo{
    width: 5vw;
    border: 2px ;
    border-radius:100mm;

}
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
div ul{
    margin: 0px 40px;
}
body{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    background-color: #e3ecf3;
}
div{
    margin: 20px 15px;
}
ol li{
    margin: 0px 40px;
}

.block{
    display:block;
}
.inline-block{
    display: inline-block;
}
.border-red{
    border: 3.5px solid red;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
.border-green{
    border: 3.5px solid green;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.border-blue{
    border: 3.5px solid blue;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.line-height{
    line-height: 8vh;
    
}

ol{
    border: 2px solid blue;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    margin: 4px 0px;
    width:300px
}
.text-cen{
    text-align: center;
}
ol li{
    margin-left: 40px;
}
input{
    display: block;
}
option{
    background-color:#15191f;
    color:#e3ecf3;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
select{
    width: 85px;
    background-color:#15191f;
    color:#e3ecf3;
    height:30px;
    border: 2px solid #15191f;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.button{
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    /* border: 2px solid #15191f; */
    border-radius: 100px;
    /* background-color: #15191f; */
}
/* .button: */
.checkbox{
    /* background-color: #15191f; */
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>All in One</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/home.css">
    <script src="../JS/home.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="">
    <nav class="flex row al-cen">
        <img id="logo" src="../random_source" alt="Error loading image">
        <ul class="flex row">
            <li id="li1"><a id="a1" href="../HTML/home.html" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
            <li id="li2"><a id="a2" href="../HTML/about.html" target="_blank">About Us</a></li>
            <li id="li3"><a id="a3" href="../HTML/services.html" target="_blank">Our Services</a></li>
            <li id="li4"><a id="a4" href="../HTML/contact.html" target="_blank">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="heading flex flex-column al-cen ju-cen">
        <h1 class="line-height">All in ONE Website</h1>
        <p>This <strong>Website</strong> aims to <i>include</i> all that has been <em>learnt</em> and keep a record of
            it for future usage.</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="border-red firstpara">
        <p><b>
                <\b>This Bold<\b>
            </b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. <br><strong>
                <\br> Has been used here and here<\br><br>
            </strong> modi molestias omnis voluptate alias unde voluptates provident hic voluptatibus ipsum deleniti
            itaque
            delectus et expedita quisquam, non soluta, harum consequuntur sapiente rem quaerat. Repellendus, impedit.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="border-green lists">
        <div class="orderdlist block border flex-row ">

            <ol id="ol1" class="inline-block" type="1">
                <h6>OL type 1</h6>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            </ol>
            <ol id="olA" class="inline-block" type="A">
                <h6>OL type A</h6>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            </ol>
            <ol id="ola" class="inline-block" type="a">
                <h6>OL type a</h6>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            </ol>
            <ol id="olI" class="inline-block" type="I">
                <h6>OL type I</h6>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            </ol>
            <ol id="oli" class="inline-block" type="i">
                <h6>OL type i</h6>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="unorderedlist">
            <ul type="square">
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            </ul>
            <ul type="circle">
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            </ul>
            <ul type="disc">
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border-blue table text-cen flex flex-column wrap">
        <h3>This is a Table</h3>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Heading-1</th>
                    <th>Heading-2</th>
                    <th>Heading-3</th>
                    <th>Heading-4</th>
                    <th>Heading-5</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Row-1-Colum-1</td>
                    <td>Row-1-Colum-2</td>
                    <td>Row-1-Colum-3</td>
                    <td>Row-1-Colum-4</td>
                    <td>Row-1-Colum-5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Row-2-Column-1</td>
                    <td>Row-2-Column-2</td>
                    <td>Row-2-Column-3</td>
                    <td>Row-2-Column-4</td>
                    <td>Row-2-Column-5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Row-3-Column-1</td>
                    <td>Row-3-Column-2</td>
                    <td>Row-3-Column-3</td>
                    <td>Row-3-Column-4</td>
                    <td>Row-3-Column-5</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="border-red forms flex flex-column">
        <h1 class="text-cen">FORMS</h1>
        <h5>Below are some types of input we can ask on forms.Include a NAME in input tags
        </h5>
        <p>We will make input tag a block element to make go to next line and make the code look clean.
            Before it was inline so elements crammmed over each other.We can add value="" to show that thing.<br>
            The diff between value and placeholder is that the placeholder gets removed whan an item is entered, wheras
            when we enter an item at place of value, it concencates in the value. Placeholder is Background, value is
            not.
            @gmail.com is value below in email. Remaining are Placeholder
        </p>
        <form action="#">
            Button <input class="button" type="button" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Checkbox<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Color<input type="color" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Date<input type="date" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Datetime<input type="datetime" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Datetime-local<input type="datetime-local" placeholder="Placeholder"><p>Just Testing</p>
            Email<input type="email" value="@gmail.com" placeholder="Placeholder">
            File<input type="file" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Hidden<input type="hidden" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Image<input type="image" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Month<input type="month" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Number<input type="number" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Password<input type="password" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Radio<input type="radio" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Range<input type="range" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Reset<input type="reset" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Search<input type="search" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Submit<input type="submit" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Tel<input type="tel" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Text<input type="text" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Time<input type="time" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Url<input type="url" placeholder="Placeholder">
            Week<input type="week" placeholder="Placeholder">

            Select from a dropdown <select>
                <option value="Option-1-Val">Option-1</option>
                <option value="Option-2-Val">Option-2</option>
                <option value="Option-3-Val">Option-3</option>
                <option value="Option-4-Val">Option-4</option>
                <option value="Option-5-Val">Option-5</option>
            </select>

        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="entities border-green">
        <h4>We use entities for displaying some character</h4>
        &lt;
        <!-- Less Than -->
        &gt;
        <!-- Greater Than -->
        &pound;
        <!-- pound -->
        &copy;
        <!-- copy -->
        &rAarr;
        <!-- Arrow -->
        &frac12;
        <!-- In form of fraction -->
        
    </div>
    <div class="border-blue semanticelements">
        <p>A dropdown button which shows whatever is written in summary and when clicked reveals what is written in detail tag.</p>
        <details>
            
            <summary>I have keys but no doors. I have space but no room. You can enter but you can't leave. What am i?</summary>
            A Keyboard.

        </details>
        <p>Now i will use a time tag</p>
        <p>We will be celebrating new year on <time datetime="2022-12-12">December 12</time> in my house.</p>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I get side scrolling

Comment: What browser and OS are you on? I’m confined to an iPad at the moment using Safari and see the full red border and there is no sideways (horizontal) scrolling. I guess you are on something that is showing a vertical scroll bar and that is taking some of the width.

Comment: Horizontal scroll bar is still there.

Comment: On a win 10 PC, opera browser

Comment: You need to allow for the width of the vertical scroll bar.

Comment: Yeah it is probably the scrollbar. I'm on Firefox Linux Desktop

Comment: Glad to know that it does not shows on Safari.

Answer (score 0):

In main tag of your website you should give width 100%:

```
width : 100%;
```

if you set 100vw your browser take overflow-x as well as your vertical scrollbar width.

Comment: This won't solve the issue as the border will still cause the element to overflow